# How to use crittercism for an android Service

Tags: android, crittercism

Is there a way to use crittercism for crash reporting of a Service ? The application is just a service without any Activity whatsoever.

I'm using the crittercism initialization in the onCreate method of the service as follows:

```
Crittercism.initialize(this, "...");
```

But the service never gets reported to the crittercism dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

One of founders of Crittercism here, we have support for android services out of the box.  Which version of the SDK are you using?  If you're on v4.5.3, try rolling back to v4.5.1 of the SDK.  There was a bug we identified with our release candidate that we're fixing right now.

http://docs.crittercism.com/downloads/downloads.html